# How to Debug in APM

Tags: debugging, arm7

I am using Arm Project Manager (APM) for writing the firmware in my ARM board. My question is: What are the live debugging features available in APM? Let's say I need to inspect the value at some pin of the CPU.

Any tutorial / video is helpful.

Comment: You mean [this tool](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/Chddefih.html) for which the documentation is marked as "Withdrawn" on infocenter.arm.com?  That's worrisome.

Comment: Also, why don't you inspect the value of the pin with an oscilloscope or DMM - Is it a BGA or QFN with inaccessible tracks?  The basic idea (which I've used in gdb) is to read the value at the memory address which stores the pin status.

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't get much help how to do debug in hardware with JTAG port using APM

Comment: when you use gdb to inspect the values, how do you do live debugging. how do you stop your processor at certain moment to inspect some value. In brief can you please describe me the debugging flow?

Comment: Briefly, `monitor reset halt`, `b main`(or other function), `continue`, `s` to desired point in program, `x addr` where addr is the desired location. Use OpenOCD to connect remotely.  I started learning with [this lab](http://claymore.engineer.gvsu.edu/~steriana/courses/424/lab2.pdf).  However, this is really a different question.

Answer (score 2):

The APM doesn't include a debugger. You need to use the debugger supplied in the ARM Software Development Toolkit.

I use the [Rowley CrossWorks tools](http://www.rowley.co.uk/) for ARM development. They come with an excellent debugger, which uses many of the more popular JTAG interfaces.

Comment: Your link was broken, and mine pointed to a broken site.  For now, the PDF of the docs (see Ch. 3 for the debugger) is at [this URL](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/DUI0040D.pdf)

Comment: i am novice in doing real time debugging in embedded. can you please point me to some pointers to get started. or please let me know the standard process used.